# IBM MobileFirst Session Affinity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, load-balancing, mobilefirst-server, ibmhttpserver

**Environment Details:**
IBM MFP 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103
IBM WAS Liberty 8.5.5.5

**Setup:**
1. MFP App is deployed in two Liberty servers.
2. Mobile devices can access the App via Webserver and the requests are routed on `round-robin` fashion properly.

**Device:**
1. Android
2. IOS

**Problem:**
1. User has logged into the App and accessing the Adapter.
2. These adapters are protected by Security test.
3. But still the request is routed to Liberty server's as round-robin by webserver.
4. Ideally, the request should be forward to the server where it is authenticated.

**Configuration:**
1. In authenticationConfig.xml - **Securitytest** & **realm** are defined.
2. Login initiates via **WL.client.Login({realmName});** realmName - Mapped in security Test
3. Adapters are protected with the Security test defined in authconfig.xml
4. Liberty Server - Manual & Unique cloneID is provided for both server in httpsession of server.xml
5. In Webserver, plugin-cfg.xml is configured for session affinity along with cloneID of each server.

```
 <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid"
 Name="/wladmin/*"></Uri>
```

Did I miss something? Why the requests are routed by WebServer to both the liberty servers after authenticating.

**Note:**
1. Plugin-cfg.xml is generated via jconsole.
2. Liberty Farm is configure and active.

Comment: Your problem description does not describe the problem or error you are facing.

Comment: What application is this mobile web? android? ios?

Comment: @IdanAdar, its hybrid Mobile app for android & ios.

Comment: MFP 7.1 is session independent by default. Is the request ending up in another server causing an issue?

Comment: After logging in, is there a session cookie? What are its contents? How does it compare to the known clones in plugin-cfg.xml?

Answer (score 0):

In MFP 7.1 by default it is session independent. Still we support session dependency but for this you need to configure. Please check this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html for more details.

Note:
If your system is operating in session-independent mode and you choose to scale back or scale up any number of servers, the user experience is unaffected. This is the advantage.